# Geting null from ArrayList in Android when extract JSONArray

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm using Volley to get information from an SQL database, from server, and I get it in a `JSONArray`. When I extract values from the `JSONArray` so I can save values to an `ArrayList`, in the `return` statement I get null in my `ArrayList`. Can anyone help with the `return` statement?

```
 @Override

public List<WorkItem> getWorkItem() {
    final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/items/all/items";

   JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d("Response", response.toString());


            try {

               arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                response = new JSONArray(response.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = jsonobject.getString("title");
                    String description = jsonobject.getString("description");
                    String state = jsonobject.getString("status");
                    String assignee = jsonobject.getString("assignee");

                    arrayList.add(new WorkItem(title, description, state, assignee));

                    arrayList.size();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.d("Error", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    jsonArrayRequest.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);
    mQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: where did you declared `arrayList` ?

Comment: public final class VolleyWorkItemRepository  implements WorkItemRepository {

    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    public static final String REQUEST_TAG = "CreateActivity";
    private static VolleyWorkItemRepository instance;
    private List<WorkItem> arrayList;

Comment: iI have another issue Im getting result more than ones ????